# Where can I get a gazetteer of common titles?

Tags: nlp

I am new to NLP. I know a little bit about wordnet -- but have never used it. I know that practitioners will often use a gazetteer to assist with language modeling tasks. I need a gazeteer of common titles like "President", "CEO", "Chairman", "Executive Director", "Chief Council" etc. Where should I go to look for such a gazetteer? Are there known sources for this sort of data? If not, how would I go about building one easily from wordnet?

Comment: I advise you ask this question on http://opendata.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If you don't mind a bit of preprocessing, you can see there : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [GATE](https://gate.ac.uk/) project has very good gazetteer resources.
You can download a list of job titles from
[the GATE ANNIE plugin gazetteer resources](http://sourceforge.net/p/gate/code/HEAD/tree/gate/trunk/plugins/ANNIE/resources/gazetteer/jobtitles.lst)